# IOS: show a view when an app start

Tags: ios, xcode, view

Everytime I launch an app I want to show a view and this view should disappear on its own (example at start I see this view that in 3 second disappear as its alpha change from 1.00 to 0.00) 
How can I get it?

Comment: do you want to show view or an image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can present the image in a modal view from the app delegate. You can use a simple animation to transition the alpha from 1.0 to 0.0, e.g.

```
imageView.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(dismissModalSelector)];
    imageView.alpha = 0.0;
} [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Use `dismissModalSelector` to set a method that removes the modal view.

It will help to set the `Default.png` image to the one you wish to display, and you may want to have a shorter animation since the default will appear for a second or two.

Comment: ok, but if I put my app in background, when I open a secondtime my app, I see another time this image?

Comment: @blackguardian: Yes. If you only want to show it the first time, then you can use `NSUserDefaults` to count the number of times the app has loaded, and then not display this screen if the app has been loaded more than 1 (or 12) times.

Comment: I want that this image is showed everytime I open the app, also when it's in background

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image for this purpose
save an image as `Default` in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Why not writing a custom view controller ? When your app is launched, set it as the root view controller of the window, and set up a timer that will make your view controllers switching.